# Как проверить дату создания файла

Tags: php

Как узнать дату создания файла, а не дату последнего изменения файла?

`filectime()` - выводит дату последнего изменения файла, почему - то...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

из документации - *В большинстве файловых систем Unix понятие времени создания файла отсутствует.*