# Сортировка массива по дате создания файла

Tags: php

```
<?php 
     $dwurl = "Tracks Page/"; 
     $array = array();  

     $dir = "all tracks";
     $files = glob("$dir/*.mp3");    

     for($i = 0; $i < count ($files); $i++){
        $array[] = $files[$i];

     }

     for ($e=0; $e < count($array); $e++) { 
        sort(filectime($array[$e]));


     echo "<li class='current-song'><a href='".$array[$e]."'>".basename(str_replace(mp3, " ", ($array[$e])))."</a></li>";

     echo "<pre style='font-size:3px;'> </pre>";

     echo "<a class='down' href='".$dwurl .basename(str_replace(mp3, "", ($files[$e])))."php'> Скачать</a>";    
   echo "<br>";

     }
 ?>
```

Как можно отсортировать этот массив по дате создания mp3-файла?

Comment: и еще вот - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465956/223826

Comment: сорян но я не понял(((

Comment: @Fenix разобрались?

Answer (score 0):

Первое надо добавить в массив дату создания файла

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count ($files); $i++){
    $array[] = [
        'name' => $files[$i],
        'time' => filectime($dir.'/'.$files[$i]),
    ];

 }
```

дальше отсортировать массив по ключу time

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){ return $a['time'] - $b['time']; });
```

ну и надо удалить лишнюю информацию

```
$result = array_column($array, 'name');
```

Comment: пожалуйста напишите полный код где у куда вставить этот цикл, можете просто изменить мой код

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил следующее:

```
$files = glob("$dir/*.mp3"); 

usort($files, function($a, $b) {
    return filectime($a) <=> filectime($b);
});
```

А вашу сортировку следовало бы удалить.

Comment: спасибо это работает но мне нужно отображать наоборот новые созданные на верху а старые в внизу как сделать помогите пж

Comment: @Fenix, поменяйте местами `$a` и `$b`. `filectime($b) <=> filectime($a)`.